# Eliminar Fila segun texto en un Txt Java

Tags: java, archivo, text

Buenas Tengo un código así:

```
String ruta = "archivo.txt";
File archivo = new File(ruta);
String texto;
String[] a;
String pre= "texto a encontrar";
  FileReader f = new FileReader(archivo);
  FileWriter f1 = new FileWriter(archivo);
  BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(f1));
 while((texto = b.readLine())!=null) {
 a = texto.split("==");
       String h = a[0];    



       if (h.equals(pre)){
          out.println("");

           f1.close();
       }
```

Lo que quiero llegar ha hacer es según un texto poder eliminar esa fila sin tener que eliminar o sobrescribir el fichero completo solo la fila en donde aparece ese texto. 
Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: No es posible. Debes guardar todo el archivo.

Comment: y es posible guardarlo en una variable y remplazar solo los caracteres  que quiero y guardar el fichero?

Comment: Eso si. Puedes leer todo el archivo de golpe en una variable, sustituir lo que quieras, y guardar la variable en el archivo de nuevo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una manera fácil de modificar todo el fichero quitando todas las filas que no contengan una determinada cadena:

```
public void eliminarFilas(String rutaAlFichero, String cadena) throws IOException{
    Path path = Paths.get(rutaAlFichero);
    List<String> lineas = Files.readAllLines(path);
    lineas = lineas.stream()
                    .filter(linea->!linea.contains(cadena))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Files.write(path, lineas);
}
```

Comment: Me fue perfecto muchas gracias

Comment: Qué elegante queda todo con streams y lambdas